# animate UITableView frame and contentOffset together

Tags: ios, uitableview, animation, iad

So I'm adding an iAd unit to the top of a UITableView. I'm creating the ad unit off-screen, then animating it into place as you're supposed to.

When the ad appears, I'd like to simultaneously animate the frame and contentOffset of the table at the same speed, so that the table appears to stay still, while in reality it's shrinking by the height of the ad and sliding its contents up at the same time.

If I animate both together, they seem to happen at different speeds and everything jumps horribly when the ad appears.

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.05 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut
                     animations:^{
                           [self.table setFrame: CGRectMake(tableFrame.origin.x,tableFrame.origin.y+50,tableFrame.size.width,tableFrame.size.height-[self getBannerHeight])];
                           [self.table setContentOffset:CGPointMake(self.table.contentOffset.x,self.table.contentOffset.y+50) animated:NO];
                           [self.adBannerView setFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,self.adBannerView.frame.size.width,self.adBannerView.frame.size.height)];
                     }
                     completion:nil];
```

If I animate the just the frame the cells move, which sucks imo. I'd like this to upset the UI as little as possible.

Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than resizing the table view and scrolling at the same time, try animating the sliding in of the ad, without resizing the table view. Then, in the completion block, set the table view frame and contentOffset without animating it.

This should have the effect you want, but during the animation, the table view will actually just be partly covered by the ad.

Comment: Of course! Thanks, I had a feeling there was a simple answer out there.